# When the projection of structure sheaf of product of a scheme $X$ with a variety $Y$ is $\mathscr O_X$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Mumford [writes](https://books.google.com/books?id=k53VCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=p1*%20o%20x%20%3D%20x%20if%20y%20is%20a%20variety%20kunneth&source=bl&ots=EgCjYVLG8f&sig=cExR_zi2OaE0L29IpmAzCSmjRwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwij5OiWsIjQAhVKQyYKHSMLD1kQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=p1*%20o%20x%20%3D%20x%20if%20y%20is%20a%20variety%20kunneth&f=false) that when $Y$ is a variety (and $X$ is a scheme over a field),

$$p_{1,*}(\mathscr O_{X\times Y})= \mathscr O_X$$

as a cor of Künneth for schemes over a field, which implies

$$p_{1,*}(p_1^*\mathscr F\otimes p_2^*\mathscr G)=\mathscr F\otimes H^0(Y,\mathscr G)$$
for $\mathscr F,\mathscr G$ quasicoherent over $X,Y$ etc.

My question is, am I missing something, or don't we obviously need $Y$ projective.

Comment: Yes, projective or at least proper over the field.

Comment: Sure, cheers---